# Rearrange intellij keymap to android studio format

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

Does anybody know how to fix AndroidStudio when it fails on reading the customized keymap out of an IntellJ-config?

I guess I spotted the reason for the crash...
AndroidStudio expects this format:

```
  <action id="CloseEditor">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl F1" />
  </action>
```

while intelliJ saves it like this

```
  <action id="CloseEditor">
    <keyboard-shortcut first-keystroke="ctrl f1" />
  </action>
```

Is there a plugin to rearrange the format, or will I write it for myself?

Answer (score 0):

I made a small plugin for this situation. You can find it [here](https://github.com/pepperonas/AnniKeymap).
Please note that the current configuration works only on IntelliJIdea14 (exporting for AndroidStudio) and AndroidStudio 1.4 (exporting for IntelliJ). Maybe I will improve the functionality later. If you have any question, feel free to ask.

**How to use:**
Download and install .jar file you find in the repo. Restart IntelliJ, click > Tools > Export for Android Studio. Now you will find a folder AnniKeymap in your root directory, copy and paste the files you find inside in to `/.AndroidStudio1.4/config/keymaps`.